# Insert data into external source/DB while using Android Architecture Components and Room

Tags: android, rest, android-room, android-architecture-components

All I read about Android Architecture Components with Room and a Single Point of Truth is about caching data in the local DB by using Room. I've crawled through countless repos but none seem to come close to solving my problem: "Pushing data **to** an external source while making use of ARCH and Room"

When retrieving data from the local DB which is not available it should get fetch it from a remote source (API). All good so far.

But how do you push data **to** the external source?

1) When you are connected to the network I can imagine you just POST/PUT to your API directly. (Or not?) And then fetch the data when it's required to cache it in the local DB. But aren't you then violating your Single Source of Truth?

2) What to do when you are not connected to a network? I'd say you insert your data into your local DB. But then how do you synchronize that data with your external source? (This is necessary since no data can be lost.)

As you can see I have no clue how to tackle this problem. And I don't think I can be the only one.

Thanks in advance for helping out =)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. I think that's how I'll do it: If the app is connected to the network I would go for your no. 1 and post it directly to your remote source (DB).

In case you are offline, I would insert it in the local database and add a flag to it. For example, you could add a Column synced and set it to false.

As soon as you are reconnected to the internet you could check your tables if they contain data rows that are marked by the flag and post them to the remote source.